# how to remove the space between number in datagridview vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

[datagridview table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF6lO.png) 
please can you help i have this problem i tried a lot of code but nothing work

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs)Handles Button4.Click

For RowsCount = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
For Each dgvr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
If dgvr.Cells(0).Value.ToString = " " Then
dgvr.Cells(0).Value = ""
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

what want to do is to remove the space between all number in the column Tel
and remove the zero and left i want all number to be like this without space or 0 like this 48802967 so please can anyone help i'm new in coding

the DataGridView is loaded from a mysql database

Comment: Why don't you replace it in the database select query? It's also not really clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to remove all spaces in the telephone number column.

Use [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) (it's the fifth column, isn't it? Then use `Cells(4)`):

```
Dim value = dgvr.Cells(4).Value
If value IsNot Nothing 
    dgvr.Cells(4).Value = value.ToString().Replace(" ", "")
End If
```

However, in general it's the best approach to do it in the first place, the database. So either remove them before you store them or at least always when you select them.

```
SELECT REPLACE(tel, ' ', '') AS Tel FROM TableName
```

---

If you also want to remove leading zeros of the phone number:

```
dgvr.Cells(4).Value = value.ToString().TrimStart("0"c).Replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: thank you so much Time for your help its work
but you didn't' tell me how to remove the zero in the left of the number phone

Comment: @MouhcinIuoanid: so you want to change `01234567` to `1234567`? Are you sure that this is not an important part of the phone number? If not , you can use `dgvr.Cells(4).Value = value.ToString().TrimStart("0"c).Replace(" ", "")`

Comment: thank you so much again for your help
this is the result i've been looking  
is the best stackoverflow